# Standard Lens Digital Cameras

Tags: digital, point-and-shoot

Are there any non-SLR digital cameras that come with a Standard or Telephoto lens?

Comment: Do you mean standard (not wide angle) or prime (not zoom)?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the community.

There are many - virtually any point and shoot has standard zoom. Many (Canon SX series, for example) have telephoto zooms.

There are also interchangeable lens cameras in the Micro 4/3 family among other mirrorless cameras.

Medium format View cameras are a valid answer to this question as well, but I guess it is not what you mean here. **EDIT** I just noticed you mentioned "digital cameras" so I guess the view camera category is not a valid answer, after all... but there certainly are some mediums with digital backs (a couple tens of thousands $$, though, and I am not completely sure they do not fall under the SLR definition)

Answer (score 1):

This question is confusing, so I'm going to answer both way I can interpret it.

Are you looking for a bundle with a mirrorless interchangeable lens camera (ILC)? Seems pointless since you can get ANY lens you want, even if it does not come with it. If you really want a bundle, then many cameras come with 2-lens kits. The second lens is always a telephoto one and the first always covers the *standard* focal-length. The catch is they those are often of poor quality which is why the bundles (called *kits*) are quite cheap.

...Or...

Are you looking for a fixed-lens camera that covers either standard (They ALL do) or telephoto focal-lengths? Most modern cameras reach at least where telephoto starts and some, called [ultra-zooms](http://www.neocamera.com/list_cameras.php?type=ultrazoom), go really far, up to 840mm.

If you know what focal-length you want covered you can use [Neocamera's Camera Finder](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php). Just put what you want in 'Widest Focal Length' and in 'Longest Focal Length'. It will find you all current cameras that match.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the mirrorless interchangeable-lens cameras, there are several non-SLR large-sensor compact cameras on the market which come with fixed normal-range (or slightly wide) lenses.

- [Leica X1](http://en.leica-camera.com/photography/compact_cameras/x1/)
- [Fujifilm FinePix X100](http://www.finepix-x100.com/) (which I'm drooling over; not yet released)
- [Sigma DP2s](http://www.sigma-dp.com/DP2s/)
- [Sigma DP1x](http://www.sigma-dp.com/DP1x/)